# Typescript: AST / TypeChecker, get the resolved type with all attributes

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, abstract-syntax-tree, typescript-generics

Looking for a way to get all attributes / declarations from the Type.
So I can make auto object transform between javascript and mongodb possible, with specific type.

I found [Typescript: TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMqciHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNwllQRwAmeANgE9kcZrXIBXSgCNo7MsgR4wiMHWIKFvHlyxY6DJiDYdNyAG7AswMABE4kOvcjyyAXyIei3n97CCABxQAFXRMKFx8AF5kdDgoMGA4fgAeDGw8AD52In8g5FDgBABrcMjkGPQi4rSyvAAaZAByCmom5AAfZtEIJuygA) already did the similar thing as what I need:

[image]
[image]

How can I extract the same info of resolved type as it does?

I tried to analyze with [ast-viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAVoGcD2JkDeAUMqciHALYQBcyWYUoA5gNwllQRwAmeANgE9kcZrXIBXSgCNo7MsgR4wiMHWIKFvHlyxY6DJiDYdNyAG7AswMABE4kOvcjyyAXyIei3sIIAOKAAq6JhQuPgAvMjocFBgwHD8ADwY2HgAfOy+AcjBwAgA1qHhyFHo+QUpxXgANMgA5BTU9cgAPg2iEPWZQA), also didn't get enough information there.

And [ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph), got almost the same info as ast-viewer.